# How do I send some input with heredoc after a sleep?

Tags: bash, shell, sleep, heredoc

I want to run a python script from a shell script and then send some input after 5 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

<path/to/python/script> << EOF
input1
EOF
```

How do I make the shell script sleep for 5 seconds and then send the input?

Comment: I think you could do this with a bash named pipe?

Comment: this isn't really a python question.  Stdin works the same way regardless of what program is receiving it.  If folks agree we should remove that tag

Comment: Could you clarify what you are actually trying to do please? And why the 5 second wait? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `{ sleep 5; echo input; } | script.py`?

Comment: So manually, I start a python script, I wait ~5 seconds until it has actually started, and then I type some input. I want the shell script to do the same thing

Comment: Surely if you just do `echo "input" | python_script` the input will still be there when your Python script eventually gets around to reading it?

Answer (score 3):

you could always put a `$(sleep 1)` in the heredoc.

```
$ sed s/world/moon/ <<-eof
> $(date)
> $(sleep 1)\
> $(date)
> hello
> world
> eof
Fri Dec 11 20:51:40 CST 2020
Fri Dec 11 20:51:41 CST 2020
hello
moon
```

note however that's not *bash* waiting to send the heredoc, that's the *heredoc* taking 1 second to render.

You could also have the belated stdin receiver be itself preceeded by a 5 second sleep:

```
$ (date; sleep 1; date; exec sed s/world/moon/) <<-eof
> hello
> world
> again
> eof
Fri Dec 11 20:53:16 CST 2020
Fri Dec 11 20:53:17 CST 2020
hello
moon
again
```

I think what you're asking is a little unusual.  You might want to ask a different question on stack overflow, about what you're trying to gain with your 5 second wait.  Perhaps there's a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it with a heardoc one-liner this is what you can do:

```bash
cat - << EOF | { cat -; sleep 5; } | path/to/python/script
input1
EOF
```

But this is not very readable. To make it more readable you can extract it into a function:

```bash
function wait_for_script() {
  { cat -; sleep 5; } | path/to/python/script
}

wait_for_script << EOF
input1
EOF
```